# Can a new official blog post also be announced on sites with their own blogs?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

Currently, Stack Exchange sites with [their own blog](http://blogoverflow.com) only link to that blog in both the footer link and the announcement link in the header. The site blog completely overrides the SE blog - there's no way for people to even know it exists if they only frequent that site.

[image]

However, [the Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) often has information that often applies to every site on the network. It's been suggested that moderators or community members watch the blog and post relevant information on the child metas. I don't think it's constructive to duplicate information that way. Is there another way a new SE blog post could be announced?

Ideas:

1. Banner like the badge notifications - "A new announcement has been posted" (SE posts are rare enough that I don't think it would be noisey)
2. Second "Blog" link (Might not be room; could be confused with the site blog)
3. Community ad
4. "Announcement" link in the header (Less confusion, but see #2)
5. Dropdown on the "Blog" link if there are two new posts available (meh)

I think the best options are 1. and 3. Or a combination of both...

Comment: Perhaps the SE blog should crosspost important enough information to all per-site blogs, given that they're all hosted on the same place?

Comment: @badπ, I dunno about that. I don't follow any per-site blogs particularly closely, but they don't seem to have the same mission as the network blog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as a reasonable compromise for now I went ahead and **made both blog links point to http://blog.stackexchange.com on each site's respective *meta***.

I figure the type of user who would be *interested* in the Stack Exchange blog, will probably be frequenting the site's meta. Everyone else, not so much.

I also figure that it's more important for the community to follow and cultivate their community blog rather than the general Stack Exchange blog as a rule, so I am comfortable with the main site linking exclusively to the community blog. Right now per:

http://blogoverflow.com/

that is

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User
- Gaming
- Security
- Bicycles
- TeX
- Photo
- Stats
- Fitness

<s>(note that the blog link change on the main site only applies to *public, launched* sites. Sorry fitness...)</s> The fitness blog is [pretty awesome](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/10/if-i-can-run-so-can-you/), actually, so let's include that too!

Comment: Good idea - I agree that the users that would want to see the blog would be on meta.