# Show recent per-site blog posts in the Featured box near the StackOverflow blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, blog-overflow, community-bulletin

When there is a new post to the SO blog, it's featured on every site in the Feature box on the top-right of the sidebar, in the **Blog** section. Only posts from the main blog show up here automatically (though I believe site moderators can manually pin blog posts there if they want.)

Below that, though, in the **Featured On Meta** section, a combination of [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from meta.SE and meta.*site*.se appears together.

[image]

Is there a way to get new posts from the per-site blogs to show up here as well?

---

I see some older questions that indicate that new posts used to be indicated in the header bar, e.g.

[Can a new official blog post also be announced on sites with their own blogs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101104/can-a-new-official-blog-post-also-be-announced-on-sites-with-their-own-blogs)

and

[Per-site blog publicity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103149/per-site-blog-publicity)

but those links are no longer present, so that notification doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Good idea... But I thought blog posts weren't supported?

Comment: There is a way... You can ask a moderator to use the Upcoming Events Sidebar to provide a link to the post - I'd expect meta consensus and all that stuff with that though.

Comment: You don't even know before a blog post will be made?

Comment: Honestly, you've got a communication breakdown. Fix that, and the rest of the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure I understand your point, but it's not really important. Obviously we can get these posts 'featured' eventually, I just thought it would be nice for the per-site blogs to get at least as much visibility as the SO blog and the per-site metas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So... They're supposed to show up. There's a limit of two blog posts in the bulletin at any one time, and the company blog has priority... But *rarely* do we actually have two company blog posts running at once. So there should almost always be at least one slot for site blog posts, *if not two.*

There's just one problem: we made a change a while back, to only list blog posts tagged "company". That way, we're not annoying y'all with [awesome articles](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/how-to-be-awesome/) about [scheduled task syntax](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/08/a-better-syntax-for-scheduled-tasks/). Which you've probably already read.

There's just one problem: *we're* tagging posts with "company", but you folks are dropping the ball. A quick check on https://stackexchange.com/blogs shows *hardly any posts* tagged "company". It's like you don't even *want* folks to read your posts.

...ok, actually it's more like a bug; this wasn't supposed to apply to all blogs. Rather than forcing you to come up with convoluted schemes to work around it, Adam has generously offered to just fix it.

Comment: I pushed a fix for this. It'll be live next time we build out.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to Shog for ---hacking up--- fixing the one blog post we already had. And boo for strikethrough not working in comments.

Comment: @Mike who said we can't use s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ in comments? ;)

Comment: ([magic](http://manytools.org/facebook-twitter/strikethrough-text/))

Comment: Using Unicode is cheating. IN ANY CONTEXT.

Comment: So that makes me a proud cheater. :D

Comment: @AdamLear So now neither marking the post as sticky nor adding the hack 'company' category to the post seems to make it appear in the featured box. This is for http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2016/02/lego-marvels-avengers-a-first-look/

Comment: Hmm, unless it takes awhile to show up.